# How to turn off the Javadoc hover in Eclipse (or selectively enable it)?

Tags: eclipse, hover, javadoc

A fellow developer dislikes the Eclipse hovering Javadoc and would like to disable it (one option), or, better yet, only selectively enable it (other option).  He's using Eclipse 3.3.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "selectively" enabling it. Based on what?

Directions below are for 3.5, I don't have 3.3 lying around to check but I'm pretty sure same settings were available.

Go to Window - Preferences; select Java -> Editor -> Hovers on left hand side. You'll have to **uncheck** the **Combined Hover** option on the right; you can then either uncheck **Javadoc** option or check it but specify a modifier key for it (in the edit box below). In the latter case javadoc hover would only appear if you hold that key.

I've got to say, though, that the inconvenience of not having Combined Handler makes this really not worth it in my opinion.

Comment: I found it fairly useful to set up a modifier key for the combined hover; the default settings were making it so that I constantly had a hover box for every element in the code, even if I only stopped the pointer long enough to click and place the edit caret.

Comment: Thanks for answering - and I agree w/your opinion (this guy is using something that looks like DOS Edit in addition to Eclipse - UGH).

Comment: This is also helpful to work around the Eclipse crash with hovers described in [bug 400626](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=400626) which is closed as NOT_ECLIPSE but the fix requires a newer version of Linux than some can install.

Comment: Over 9 years later, this is still helpful with version 2023-09 (4.29.0), because the IDE is still crashing suddenly due to hovers when a javadoc is opened, even with updated software (which is fine, I do not need or want browser support with something as simple as hover documentation)

Answer (score 6):

You could go to

```
 Preferences / Java / Editor / Hover
```

and untick the "Combined Hover" option: no more popup.

Then you would have:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>: open the external javadoc if javadoc archive or directory has been associated with your project (and if some javadoc has been generated)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, followed by <kbd>J</kbd>: open the javadoc view, with the same content than the popup previously seen on mouse hovering.

Comment: I accepted the other answer because it had more details - I like this answer as well, though.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In Eclipse 3.6 you can now specify a modifier key to be pressed down for the Combined Hover to be activated. This way, you can have the old behavior without the automatic popups. The automatic popups were driving me crazy, often obscuring something I was trying to read.