# How to Disable Code Preview Popup on Hover over Code Fold in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, popup, hover, editor, fold

When I use Eclipse to code Java programs,
I can fold a block of codes, for example: a method or a comment.
And When I fold the block, there will be a "plus(+)" mark appearing on the left side of the editor in Eclipse.
If you hover your mouse over the mark, Eclipse will pop-up a frame showing those folded codes.
I feel it's annoying, but I can not find an option to disable it.
Is there an option to disable it?

thanks, mate!

Comment: I reported this as a Bug-Enhancement on the Eclipse bugzilla site: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=571551

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this can be disabled right now (Eclipse 3.5)

You can [disable popup on "javadoc hovering"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540036/how-to-turn-off-the-javadoc-hover-in-eclipse-or-selectively-enable-it) (sort of), but not on folder marks.